# Dynamic variable name syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Another newbie question that has me stuck badly.

I have three variables

```
var state1
var state2
var state3
```

I need to access one of them on a .click event depending on a property of the clicked object.

How do I access the correct variable? Basically I need to for the variable name by adding "state" and the correct number together.

I will update this post soon with some code in case it's needed.

```
var backstate1;
var backstate2;
var backstate3;
var currentFrame;

function hotspotHover(){
var currentElement = this;
var daName =this.name;
$("#hotspot" +daName).hover(

    function() { 
    $("img.changeOutline").prop("src", currentElement.outlinesArray[currentFrame]);
    $("#outlines").show(); 
    }, 
    function() { 
    $("#outlines").hide(); 
    }
).click(function() {
    var backstateLevelNumber = currentElement.backStateLevel; //not working
    window['backstate'+ backstateLevelNumber]=currentFrame; //trying to set backstate+number to current frame variable
    hoverClick(currentElement.defaultFrame);
    checkReverse();
    checkSeqLoop();
});

};
```

Comment: where are they declared? what's the code that tries to access them?

Comment: I woud use an array for this: `var state=[state1, state2, state3]` and accessing them by `state[number]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an array would solve your problem:

```
var states = [null, null, null];
```

Accessing them would then be: (Assuming `currentStateId` being the current state number)

```
var currentState = state[currentStateId] //Access state
```

And for setting:

```
states[currentStateId] = "State"; //Set State
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the states as an array:

```
var states = [ 'state1', 'state2'];
var stateNumber = 0;
var state = states[stateNumber];
```

Comment: It could be a proper answer if restated.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. Tries to restate the answer.

Comment: What I still don't seem to grasp is how would I then declare a value for the state1 or state2? I'm trying to do basically this:
If clicked object has statelevel==1 then modify the value of state1 to be currentFrame.

Comment: Can't you use `window[ states[number] ] = currentFrame;`