# JavaScript post with declared parameters

Tags: javascript, php

I’m looking to be able to edit an individual line in a php loop. I have this script here that I think is almost perfect, except I don’t know how to add the Value to the “PriorityForm”.

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function PriorityInfo(Value) {
      $.post("updatenote.php?ID="+Value, { Note: PriorityForm.Note.value},
              function(output) {
                   $("#Priority"+Value).html(output).show();
                   });
      }
</script>
```

The (Value) in “PriorityInfo(Value)” changes. I’ve gotten the Value to add to everything but “PriorityForm”. For example, { Note: PriorityForm.Note.value} needs to be { Note: PriorityForm9.Note.value} if the Value is 9. I’ve tried

```
Note: PriorityForm+ Value.Note.value
Note: PriorityForm+ (Value).Note.value
Note: PriorityForm+ “Value”.Note.value
Note: “PriorityForm”+ Value.Note.value
```

This cause the JavaScript not to run so I’m pretty sure it’s a syntax error.
My mistake, here's the PHP code:

```
   <?php
   $info0 = "SELECT * FROM CT:GTMQuestionPoints WHERE Question = 'Priority' AND PointLossNote NOT LIKE ''";
    $rs0=odbc_exec($connq,$info0);
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs0)) {
    $ID = "" . $row["ID"] . "";
    $Note = "" . $row["PointLossNote"] . "";
    $Points = "" . $row["Points"] . "";
    echo '
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 700px"><form name="PriorityForm'.$ID.'"><input name="Note" type="text" value ="'.$Note.'" style="width: 700px"></td>
    <td style="width: 100px"><input name="Points" type="text" value ="' . $Points . '" style="width: 100px"></td></form>
    <td style="width: 180px"><input name="updatepriority" type="button" value="Update" onclick="PriorityInfo(&#39;'.$ID.'&#39;)"><div id="Priority'.$ID.'"></div></td>
    <td style="width: 180px"><form method="POST" action="rmsdeletenote.php?Priority=' . $Note . '"><input name="modify" type="submit" value="Remove"></td></form>
    </tr>
    </table>
    ';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Use an array or object instead of variable variables. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11770474/218196 and many others: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+dynamic+variable+name

Comment: What PHP loop? If you want to ask a question about PHP, post your PHP code.

Comment: What *is* `PriorityForm`? Where is it declared, what value does it contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Step one, PHP on the primary page,

```
<?php
;//extend the form around the loop, and get rid of the form for the remove button (replacing with javascript)//
echo '<form name="PriorityForm">';

$info0 = "SELECT * FROM CT:GTMQuestionPoints WHERE Question = 'Priority' AND PointLossNote NOT LIKE ''";
$rs0=odbc_exec($connq,$info0);

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs0)) {
$ID = "" . $row["ID"] . "";
$Note = "" . $row["PointLossNote"] . "";
$Points = "" . $row["Points"] . "";
//give each field name a unique name//
echo '      
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width: 700px"><input name="Note'.$ID.'" type="text" value ="'.$Note.'" style="width: 700px"></td>
<td style="width: 100px"><input name="Points'.$ID.'" type="text" value ="' . $Points . '" style="width: 100px"></td>
<td style="width: 180px"><input name="updatepriority" type="button" value="Update" onclick="PriorityInfo(&#39;'.$ID.'&#39;)"><div id="Priority'.$ID.'"></div></td>
<td style="width: 180px"><input name="modify" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="Remove(&#39;'.$ID.'&#39;)">

</tr>
</table>
';
}
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Step two: JavaScript on the primary page,

```
<!-- send the specific ID and serialize everything else to the updatenote.php page-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function PriorityInfo(Value) {
$.post("updatenote.php?ID="+Value, 
 $('form[name="PriorityForm"]').serialize(), 
 function (output) {
 $("#Priority"+Value).html(output).show();
});
}
</script>
<!-- send the specific ID to the deletenote.php page-->
<script type="text/jscript">
function Remove(Value) {
location.href = "deletenote.php?ID="+Value;
}
</script>
```

Step three: Additional/replacement  php code for updatenote.php,

```
// get the ID//
If(!empty($_REQUEST['ID'])){$ID = ($_REQUEST['ID']);}

//add field name and ID to isolate the correct one//
$Note = "Note" . $ID;
$Points = "Points" . $ID;

//then retrieve only the one with the ID
If(!empty($_POST[$Note])){$NoteResult = $_POST[$Note];}
If(!empty($_POST[$Points])){$PointsResult = $_POST[$Points];}

echo $ID;
echo '<br>';
echo $NoteResult;
echo '<br>';
echo $PointsResult;
```

This may not be the cleanest way to do it, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your POST argument, "{ Note: PriorityForm.Note.value}", you're using PriorityForm as though it's an object. But based on the code you provided, you don't have a "PriorityForm" variable declared anywhere. So instead, you might want to consider fetching the value from the text input named "Note" using jQuery. There are a number of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PriorityInfo(Value) {
    var args = new Object();
    args["Note"] = $("input[name='Note']").value;
    $.post("updatenote.php?ID="+Value, args, 
        function(output){
            //other code here   
        });
}
</script>
```